# Android Camera passing bitmap from Camera Intent to MainActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, callback, camera

I am trying to take a picture and set it in my MainActivity to an ImageView.
I want to have my camera activity as a seperate class so i tried the following:
MainActivity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.action_button:
            Intent camera = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Camera.class);
            startActivityForResult(camera ,CAMERA_IDENTIFITER);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("onActivityResult","Sucessfully callbacked!"); //This one wont be executed!
    switch(requestCode) {
        case (CAMERA_IDENTIFITER) : {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getParcelableExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my camera Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    pm = getPackageManager();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(!isFromActivityResult){
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }
}
public void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch {...}
        if (photoFile != null) {
            pictureTaken = true;
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    } 
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            bitmap = ImageFileHandler.handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(this, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath)));
            //mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    bitmap);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            Log.d("onActivityResult","finish() executed!"); //This one gets executed!
            finish();
        } catch {...}
    }
}
```

The camera intent is starting properly but when i take a picture i dont get back to the onActivityResult in my MainActivity , i'm stuck in the Camera intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onStart() gets called after onActivityResult() is being executed. Hence starting camera intent again and again. Put Logs and test your self.
To solve the issue
Keep a boolean variable in your activity isFronActivityResult. Keep default value as false and do isFromActivityResult = true; inside onActivityResult(). In onStart do the following:

```
          @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            if(!isFromActivityResult)
              dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            bitmap = ImageFileHandler.handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(this, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath)));
            //mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    bitmap);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            isFromActivityResult = true;// add this line
            finish();
        } catch {...}
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it, i'm now returning to Camera activity but not to MainActivity.

Comment: are you not getting any exception?
please try putting log before finish() and see if it executes.

Comment: Yes, the log is getting executed, after that i'm getting a
    E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 23971076)
but i dont know what that is.

I also put a log in the result method in the main, this one isnt executed.

Comment: I have tried the sample app, and it works fine on my end. Please see explicitly if finish() is being executed. It would be help if you could update your code.

Comment: Updated the code and my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: as an immediate hack you can do this in onStart()
if(!isFromActivityResult){
              dispatchTakePictureIntent();
}else{ 
finish();
}

Although on my side, similar code is working fine, I guess you can also try this hack

Comment: Is not working for me, i'm stuck in the camera Activity.

Comment: ok, I got the issue. the thing is your are trying to send a lot of huge data inside your resultIntent, which is causing "E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! (parcel size = 23971076)", the proper way in my opinion should be to write your image in a file and then pass the path of that file fron resultIntent. This must solve your issue definitely.

Comment: Finally got it to work, thank you very much for your solution!